# Is possible to use iscroll in dialog popup?

Tags: jquery-mobile, popup, iscroll

I am working for mobile app. I am showing popup with content, If content is too long i feel to use scroll. Is possible to use iscroll in dialog popup?

```
$('#checkout').click(function() {
        var jqxhr = $.post("/app/Trip/checkout", {
            }, function(missing_info) {
                $('#checkout').simpledialog( {
                    'mode': 'blank',
                    'prompt': false,
                    'forceInput': false,
                    'useModal': true,
                    'fullHTML': missing_info
                })
            });
    });
```

I am getting popup with content but don't know how to implement iscroll in dialog. isroll for normal div working fine for me. This popup is jQuery mobile simple dialog. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes of course you can use iscroll for a pop up div but that popup should be nested under a parent which should be a direct child of a body. set no styles for the parent and then take the id of popup and set iscroll once content is added. 
var tempscroll;
tempscroll = new iScroll('id_of_popup');
thatsi